# NativeScript BottomNavigation - set dynamically created page-router-outlets

Tags: angular, nativescript

I would like to set up dynamically `TabContentItem` components with `page-router-outlet` inside in the `BottomNavigation`. I am using NS(6.1) with Angular8

Something like:

```
<BottomNavigation [items]="contentItems">

    <TabStrip [items]="stripItems"></TabStrip>

</BottomNavigation>
```

where

```
contentItems: TabStripItem[];

...

    let stripItem = new TabStripItem();
    stripItem.title = "tab title";
    stripItem.iconSource = 'icon source';
    this.stripItems.push(stripItem);
```

and

```
contentItems: TabContentItem[];
...
    let contentItem = new TabContentItem();
    contentItem.content = ???;
    contentItems.push(contentItem);
```

I can dynamically set the content of each `TabContentItem` to a `StackLayout` for instance and everything works as expected but struggling setting it up with `PageRouterOutlet`.

Also, I have successfully set up the `TabStrip` and the `TabContentItem` items statically as described in the documentation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not advisable to create dynamic tabs, I'm not even sure how you would manage dynamic routing module. It's suppose to be static, you should know where you want to navigate to upfront. I doubt the design pattern you are looking for is even possible when you do the same with Angular on web.

Comment: I have a set of tabs that I want to show based on user-specific logic. So the only possible way as of now is to set the strip items and the content items upfront because using `*ngIf` does not seem to work properly. It pushes the conditional tabs at the end and does not keep the order.

Comment: ... The routing for each outlet is pre-defined. Setting the bottom navigation items in `ngOnInit` seems to be the only possible as of now at least.

Comment: Yes, that would work - setting the items in ngOnInit. Binding is not supported in Tab / Bottom navigation components.

Comment: "Binding is not supported in Tab / Bottom navigation components" ... I noticed that too, yes. But I still cannot figure out how to create the page-router-outlets and set them for the tab content items in the `ngOnInit`.

Comment: [jeasyui](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo-angular/main/index.php?plugin=Tabs&theme=material-teal&dir=ltr&pitem=&sort=asc)  has a dynamic tab component.. Look at the source code below the example. Maybe this will work in Nativescript's BottomNavigation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution to the question but the workaround is to put `*ngIf` conditionals to all the strip items and content items. In this way, the ones in question will not be pushed to the end of the list and the order will be preserved.

```
<BottomNavigation>

    <TabStrip>
        <TabStripItem *ngIf="true">...</TabStripItem>

        <TabStripItem *ngIf="actualCondition">...</TabStripItem>

        <TabStripItem *ngIf="true">...</TabStripItem>

    </TabStrip>

    <TabContentItem *ngIf="true">...</TabContentItem>

    <TabContentItem *ngIf="actualCondition">...</TabContentItem>

    <TabContentItem *ngIf="true">...</TabContentItem>

</BottomNavigation>
```